# Animate scaffold background color

Tags: flutter, dart

like the title I'm trying to change with animation the `Scaffold background-color`. On onPageChanged `PageView` I trigger the animation. So far so good. The problem is with more colors. I mean, I have to take the colors from an API and when the user scrolls the card (`PageView`) I have to fit the color of that card.
Any suggestions?

This is the current code (with preview) for 2 colors: [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/39f04992ee3f3e061fb678610c56f824).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What issues are you having? Have you done anything with the API yet?

Comment: Is your issue that you need one color for each page, but the `ColorTween` only takes 2 colors?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore the API is in working so, for now, for I only have the specifications and in the meanwhile, I'm mocking the data

Comment: So is your issue what @MichaelP. described?

Comment: @MichaelP. exactly I have to found any solution to be able to have more colors as many the cards and trigger the animation

Comment: @Shifenis I think I found you a solution. I'm testing it right now

Comment: try AnimatedContainer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`TweenSequence<Color>`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/TweenSequence-class.html)

Assuming the weight of each color in the sequence is the same, you can find a given color with `index / colors.length` as I show in the `onPageChanged` callback.

Given this, `_controller.animateTo(index / colors.length)` will take the duration specified in the `AnimationController` to animation in either direction to from the current color to the new color.

Here's a [live demo](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/5c6247687d4595dde3f69a7e6008f14e)

Here's the relevant code (only showing what was changed from yours). I changed the duration and animation physics for personal preference. By all means, use what you prefer.

```dart
class _HomepageScreenState extends State<HomepageScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<Color> animation;

  final colors = <TweenSequenceItem<Color>>[
      TweenSequenceItem(
        weight: 1.0,
        tween: ColorTween(begin: Colors.red, end: Colors.blue),
      ),
      TweenSequenceItem(
        weight: 1.0,
        tween: ColorTween(begin: Colors.blue, end: Colors.green),
      ),
      TweenSequenceItem(
        weight: 1.0,
        tween: ColorTween(begin: Colors.green, end: Colors.yellow),
      ),
      TweenSequenceItem(
        weight: 1.0,
        tween: ColorTween(begin: Colors.yellow, end: Colors.red),
      ),
    ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
      vsync: this,
    );

    animation = TweenSequence<Color>(colors).animate(_controller)..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: animation.value,
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: PageView.builder(
                physics: new PageScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: colors.length,
                controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8),
                onPageChanged: ((int index) {
                  _controller.animateTo(index / colors.length);
                }),
                itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.only(left: i % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 15, bottom: 20),
                    child: Container(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Shifenis No problem! I learned something new too, and I'll definitely be using this is future apps!

Comment: I get "The argument type 'ColorTween' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Animatable<Color>'", is there is any latest way of doing it? This looks outdated.

Comment: @praveenkumar unfortunately I haven't done anything with Flutter in more than 6 months so I don't have the SDK on my computer right now to test. Looking at the documentation for `TweenSequence` and `Tween`, it looks like you'll want to replace `ColorTween(..)` with `Tween<Color>(..).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.ease))`. I'm having difficulty testing it on dartpad but I know it compiles.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

> full example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'stackoverflow question',
      home: SafeArea(
        top: false,
        bottom: true,
        child: HomepageScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomepageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomepageScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomepageScreenState createState() => _HomepageScreenState();
}

class _HomepageScreenState extends State<HomepageScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController? _controller;
  Animation<Color>? animation;
  
  final colors = <TweenSequenceItem<Color>>[
      TweenSequenceItem(
        weight: 1.0,
        tween: Tween<Color>(begin: Colors.red, end: Colors.blue),
      ),
      TweenSequenceItem(
        weight: 1.0,
        tween: Tween<Color>(begin: Colors.blue, end: Colors.green),
      ),
      TweenSequenceItem(
        weight: 1.0,
        tween: Tween<Color>(begin: Colors.green, end: Colors.yellow),
      ),
      TweenSequenceItem(
        weight: 1.0,
        tween: Tween<Color>(begin: Colors.yellow, end: Colors.red),
      ),
    ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
      vsync: this,
    );

    animation = TweenSequence<Color>(colors).animate(_controller!)..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: animation!.value,
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: PageView.builder(
                physics: new PageScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: colors.length,
                controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8),
                onPageChanged: ((int index) {
                  _controller!.animateTo(index / colors.length);
                }),
                itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.only(left: i % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 15, bottom: 20),
                    child: Container(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```